# Xamarin Forms Navigation in Modal Page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have pushed a new `ModalPage` onto my current `NavigationPage` using `await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ProfilePage());` I cannot figure out how to create a `NavigationPage` inside the `ModalPage`.  I want to load another page, wrapping inside a `NavigationPage` so that the loaded page has a navigation bar and back button to be able to return to the `ModalPage` (ProfilePage).

I am trying to achieve:

> NavigationPage > ModalPage > New NavigationPage

I have tried creating a new `NavigationPage` inside the `ModalPage` and pushing the new page onto the `NavigationPage` but nothing happens. e.g.

```
var navigationPage = new NavigationPage(this);
navigationPage.PushAsync(new Page());
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var page = new NavigationPage(new MyPage());
Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Doesnt this start a new NavigationStack?

Comment: Yes, but in the context of the modal, which is what he wanted.  The modal and the non-modal navigation stacks will exist independently of each other.

Comment: How can you then push to this new Modal Navigation stack?